# jQuery: Different ajaxStart and ajaxStop for different events

Tags: jquery, ajax

Okay, I've created little page where different elements trigger different AJAX calls.

If I had only one loading image I'd be good off with ajaxStart and ajaxStop. But I want to have different loading images to appear on different AJAX calls.

What would work of course is something like:

```
$("img#loader").show();

$.ajax({
    complete:function()
    {
        $("img#loader").hide();
    }
});
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: try with image path with `html` like `$(obj).html("<img src='"+url+"' width='500px' height='350px'/>").css({opacity: 0});`

Comment: `img#loader` is a pointless selector. Use `#loader` instead.

Comment: `img#loader` and `#loader` are two very different selectors... by itself I fail to see the pointlessness in it. Only people can make it pointless, if they don't leverage it's power.

Comment: @netbrain, why is it different? I can't see an case where #loader and img#loader are different (unless you have two elements with same ID, which breaks the specs)

Comment: You could have two different pages, where the one page has a div as a cointainer and the other a span, for block and inline elements. would then be natural to have span#myId and div#myId, they serve the same content but in different wrapping. At least, that is how i see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try generating the ajax image dynamically and remove on success function.Below is an example:

> var loader = "`<div id='loader'></div>`";

you may define specific style for the id loader in your stylesheet
 or you could supply it immediately using jquery.you can even add overlays as per your need

> ```
> var panelOverlay= $("<div id='panelOverlay'></div>").css({top:top, left:0,position:fixed, width:"100%", height:"100%", background:'#222', opacity:'.7'});
> ```

then display it  before any  ajax calls you make:
then load

```
    $("#somediv").append(loader);
    $("#loader").show();
    $("#loader").fadeIn(400).html('<img align="absmiddle" src="/path/to/image/ajax-loader1.gif" />...Loading');
```

then you make your ajax calls

```
    $.ajax({
        url     :   ""

          ...
```

`

then after success function you could remove the loading image

```
        success :function(html){
            if(<your condition>){           

                                   ...
                                   ...
                $("#loader").fadeOut('slow',function(){$("#loader").remove();
```

I hope u got it ... load on the fly and remove when done!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this it exactly what I'm not looking for since it's creating so much overhead.

What I'm searching for is something like ajaxStart and ajaxStop but only for specific AJAX calls.

Comment: then place an empty hidden div in your document eg <div id='loading'></div> then call $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
   $(this).html("<your image>").show();
 });

Comment: try adding different ajax handlers for different elements and use different loading images for different handlers